# Darken part of an image using GD

Tags: php, image, gd

I've got a jpg image and I want to return the same image, with a "highlight" effect.

Basically, I want to pass the script the xy coords, and redraw the image darkened, with an ellipse that remains in the original colouring.

Initially I did this by creating a second image, same dimensions, and drawing a white elipse, then merging them together at 40% or so.  The effect works, but the "highlighted" area is obviously a bit washed out.

Anyone know how I can basically delete that ellipse so it is purely transparent and then merge it on top of the original for a clear highlight?

Comment: How about the opposite approach to your original - make a new image that is black/darker *apart* from a transparent ellipse and merge?

Comment: I don't understand your question. If it's completely transparent, how can it act as a highlight? Have you tried reducing the opacity from 40% to say 20%?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a png for the second image with the elipse being completely transparent while the area that you want darkened has an alpha of 20% (or whatever works best). When you merge the images, you can use imagecopy instead of imagecopymerge as the alpha (transparent) value is included in the second image already.